# How to speed up the code - searching through a dataframe takes hours

Tags: python, csv, python-3.x, pandas

I've got a CSV file containing the distance between centroids in a GIS-model in the next format:

```
InputID,TargetID,Distance
1,2,3050.01327866
1,7,3334.99565217
1,5,3390.99115304
1,3,3613.77046864
1,4,4182.29900892
...
...
3330,3322,955927.582933
```

It is sorted on origin (`InputID`) and then on the nearest destination (`TargetID`).

For a specific modelling tool I need this data in a CSV file, formatted as follows (the numbers are the centroid numbers):

```
distance1->1, distance1->2, distance1->3,.....distance1->3330
distance2->1, distance2->2,.....
.....
distance3330->1,distance3330->2....distance3330->3330
```

So no InputID's or TargetID's, just the distances with the origins on the rows and the destinations on the columns:
(example for the first 5 origins/destinations)

```
 0,3050.01327866,3613.77046864,4182.29900892,3390.99115304
 3050.01327866,0,1326.94611797,1175.10254872,1814.45584129
 3613.77046864,1326.94611797,0,1832.209595,3132.78725738
 4182.29900892,1175.10254872,1832.209595,0,1935.55056767
 3390.99115304,1814.45584129,3132.78725738,1935.55056767,0
```

I've built the next code, and it works. But it is so slow that running it will take days to get the 3330x3330 file. As I am a beginner in Python I think I am overlooking something...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
file=pd.read_csv('c:\\users\\Niels\\Dropbox\\Python\\centroid_distances.csv')
df=file.sort_index(by=['InputID', 'TargetID'], ascending=[True, True])
number_of_zones=3330
text_file = open("c:\\users\\Niels\\Dropbox\\Python\\Output.csv", "w")

for origin in range(1,number_of_zones):
    output_string=''
    print(origin)
    for destination in range(1,number_of_zones):
        if origin==destination:
            distance=0
        else:
            distance_row=df[(df['InputID']==origin) & (df['TargetID'] == destination)] 
            # I guess this is the time-consuming part
            distance=distance_row.iloc[0]['Distance']
        output_string=output_string+str(distance)+','
    text_file.write(output_string[:-1]+'\n') #strip last ',' of line
text_file.close()
```

Could you give me some hints to speed up this code?

Comment: I don't understand the CSV format. Can you provide an explicit input/output example?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

IIUC, all you need is `pivot`.  If you start from a frame like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(columns="InputID,TargetID,Distance".split(","))
df["InputID"] = np.arange(36)//6 + 1
df["TargetID"] = np.arange(36) % 6 + 1
df["Distance"] = np.random.uniform(0, 100, len(df))
df = df[df.InputID != df.TargetID]
df = df.sort(["InputID", "Distance"])

>>> df.head()
   InputID  TargetID   Distance
2        1         3   6.407198
3        1         4  43.037829
1        1         2  52.121284
4        1         5  86.769620
5        1         6  96.703294
```

and we know the InputID and TargetID are unique, we can simply `pivot`:

```
>>> pv = df.pivot(index="InputID", columns="TargetID", values="Distance").fillna(0)
>>> pv
TargetID          1          2          3          4          5          6
InputID                                                                   
1          0.000000  52.121284   6.407198  43.037829  86.769620  96.703294
2         53.741611   0.000000  27.555296  85.328607  59.561345   8.895407
3         96.142920  62.532984   0.000000   6.320273  37.809105  69.896308
4         57.835249  49.350647  38.660269   0.000000   7.151053  45.017780
5         72.758342  48.947788   4.212775  98.183169   0.000000  15.702280
6         32.468329  83.979431  23.578347  30.212883  82.580496   0.000000
>>> pv.to_csv("out_dist.csv", index=False, header=False)
>>> !cat out_dist.csv
0.0,52.1212839519,6.40719759732,43.0378290605,86.769620064,96.7032941473
53.7416111725,0.0,27.5552964592,85.3286070586,59.5613449796,8.89540736892
96.1429198049,62.5329836475,0.0,6.32027280686,37.8091052942,69.8963084944
57.8352492462,49.3506467609,38.6602692461,0.0,7.15105257546,45.0177800391
72.7583417281,48.9477878574,4.21277494476,98.183168992,0.0,15.7022798801
32.4683285321,83.9794307564,23.578346756,30.2128827937,82.5804959193,0.0
```

The [reshaping](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reshaping.html) section of the tutorial might be useful.

Comment: FWIW I did the same thing as above with a data set of your size (with 3330 ids) which has substantially more rows and the pivot operation still finished inside of 9 seconds.  Thumbs up to DSM's pivot solution